# Partial differentiation problem (FOC)

Tags: partial-derivative

I am having troubles to partially differentiate the following:

$ \frac{\delta (v_i-4b_i)^{1/2}*\frac{b_i-c}{a}}{\delta b_i}=0 $

Mostly I am unsure, which rules are applied here and in what order. So far, I made some attempts, but without any success. Maybe someone can help me understanding the applied procedure here and show me how to do it and what the result is.

Comment: You want the partial of the whole numerator?

Comment: Yes, the whole numerator differentiated with respect to b_i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial b_i}\left( \sqrt{v_i -4b_i}\cdot \frac{b_i-c}{a}\right) \\ = \frac{\partial (\sqrt{v_i-4b_i})}{\partial b_i}\cdot \frac{b_i-c}{a} + \frac{\partial (\frac{b_i-c}{a} ) }{\partial b_i} \cdot \sqrt{v_i-4b_i} \\ = \frac{-4}{2\sqrt{v_i-4b_i}} \cdot \frac{b_i-c}{a} + \frac 1a \cdot\sqrt{v_i-4b_i}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see my mistake!